# Is there any auto-escaping way for grep with variables?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, escaping

I have a text in a variable I want to be matched exactly as it is, but it may contains special characters (like dot), I tried to guarantee doing this way:

```
MATCH=$(cat SOMEFILE | sed 's/\./\\./g')
LINES=$(grep "[[:space:]]$MATCH\$" OTHERFILE) # retrieves lines ending with the matched content
```

It worked for now, but I was wondering if there is any better way? And if by chance `MATCH` contain another special character as `[`, `|` or any other regex?

Comment: [Here a sample](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32355/escaping-of-meta-characters-in-basic-extended-posix-regex-strings-in-grep), I wonder if there is a simpler way to do that.

Comment: Can you provide your sample input and expected output?

Comment: This case I am searching for IP address, but it could be anything, like a free text.

Comment: In that case you will be better off using PHP/perl/Java for better regex support and escaping features.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a dd-wrt router, there is no support to that complex languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own grep solution:

```
sgrep() {
    EXPR=
    while :; do
        [ "$1" == '--' ] && shift && break
        [ -z "$1" ] && break
        if [ "${1:0:2}" == '-t' ]; then
            EXPR="$EXPR$(echo "${1:2}" | sed 's/[][()\.^$?*+]/\\&/g')"
        elif [ "${1:0:2}" == '-e' ]; then
            EXPR="$EXPR${1:2}"
        else
            EXPR="$EXPR$1"
        fi
        shift || break
    done
    egrep "$EXPR" "$@"
}
```

The usage sample:

```
sgrep -e^ -t192.168 -e[0-9.]*[[:space:]] -- /proc/net/arp
```

Everything starting with `-t` is considered text and is escaped, arguments starting with `-e` is concatenated to the raw expression as well as other cases, after the first `--` comes the `grep` arguments itself.